# What color is suitable for IT company?

Tags: logo, color-theory, critique

What is the best colors for logo of a IT/Web Dev company? I have created sample.

[image: samples]

Comment: I'm not sure if one can answer this question. Here is only a personal view as answer possible, I think. If really all other companys use blue, don't do it or do you want to be a mass product?

Comment: I run this business locally. Not a huge one. Because just started.

Comment: How long is a piece of string?

Comment: Hey Achintha, welcome to GD.SE! Critique questions are a sort of grey area here, they _can_ be asked, but they'll only be on topic if they will help a broader set of people ([see here](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/570/8708)). Hopefully you got some good information from Scott's awesome answer. If it matters to you, we could completely re-work your question to fit Scott's answer so that it will be on-topic (send a message to @JohnB in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/graphic-design-corner) if you'd like help with that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is completely off-topic and generally unanswerable. And I voted to close this.

However, "which looks better" should **rarely** be a factor in coloring a logotype. The more appropriate question would be ***"which convey's our message better?"***

**Colors have meaning**. In general, color choice for any logo isn't an accident or an arbitrary choice. Using a specific color or color palette can *completely* alter the public perception of any company.

Think about your color options you've posted....

**Red / Yellow / Orange** part of the color wheel. What do you associate with those colors? What logotypes use relatively the same color palette? Fast food. Every fast food chain in America is based on the red / yellow / orange palette. Why? Because those color promote desire, speed, emergency, energy, and cheerful or anxious feelings. The restaurants want you to feel good about going there and they want you to think it'll be a fast, pleasurable, experience. They want you to get in and leave, so they use a palette which promotes a sense of urgency on your part.

**Blue** areas of the color wheel... What businesses or services use blue as a basis for their palette? What logos do you see in blue? Primarily, emergency services - police, EMT services, hospitals, banks, and other financial institutions to some degree. Blue promotes a sense of security, help, assistance, stability, reliability, knowledge, power. These companies and services want you to think they are trustworthy and professional so they use a palette which promotes these feeling.

You need to determine **where you want your company to stand** in terms of public perception not simply "what looks better." Design, believe it or not, is not always about what looks better. There's a **purpose to it** and thought behind it. A good designer understands the choices they make.

Red / orange may be entirely appropriate if you want to convey a sense of emergency primarily. Where blue may be better if you want to convey a sense of trust over speed.

As for your question... you may as well ask, "Should I take Wednesday off or Thursday?" Everyone here will simply be guessing because we don't know your specific needs or desires.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I got the idea what I think. As a web dev company I will go with blue. Because I need to build trust and show that its a reliable.

Answer (score 0):

I like the blue one personally.  Maybe a blue with more grey in it even.  Blue seems to be a techy color that a lot of comapanies are going with these days.